# How to turn picture into circular object?

Tags: texturing

I'm having a heck of a time trying to figure out how to turn an object that was created from importing a picture as a plane into a circular object. This is important to me because I later want to turn this into a circular mesh only, not a square mesh.

[image]

I followed the whole tutorial here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ucs4E2VBUo4, but it doesn't seem to work for me, the object still shows up as a square. Any help appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Create a circle and use the same material?

Comment: I'm kind of new to blender, can you explain what you mean by "use the same material?" I have the circle created. When I am on the circle object, and do import image as plane, I just get the square image again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a circle (*Fill Type > N-Gon*):

[image]

Select the circle, shift select the image as plane and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> > *Link Materials*:

[image]

If the image is too small and you have to reajust its size, select the circle, switch to *Edit* mode, select all, open the *UV Editor*, select the image and move and scale the UV until you're good:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, everything makes sense until I get to trying to link it. I created my circle on top of the image, so I think it might already be linked. Since the only option I have now is "unlink." Yet the circle and image are still showing up as two separate objects.

Comment: I just did it when in separate positions. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, from what i understand you want your painting on a circle, does my method work for you? Sure the image will be on another object than your image as plane, but is it a problem? You can still make a circle from your image as plane instead of creating a new object but is it really necessary?